# Unable to connect my Eclipse IDE to Github

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, github, automated-tests

When trying to perform my first commit into my Git hub account with the help of eclipse IDE unable to do my first commit.
Unable to connect my Eclipse IDE with my Git hub account.
Getting the below error.

[image]]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to connect my eclipse IDE with my Git Hub Account and want to perform commit and push based on requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put your actual password into the password field?

It is not secure. So GitHub has stopped accepting plain password recently.

You can create your personal access token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens

Then put it in the password field instead of your real password.